# HIVE INSERT Into from Select

Tags: hive, insert

I want to insert a result of a count(*) into my hive table:

```
    hive -e "use eapi;INSERT into searchresults 'ANZHAUS_GES','Null',(select count(*) from adpubsdmdata WHERE ANZHAUS_GES>=0 && ANZHAUS_GES<=0);"
```

and I get Result:

> Missing table at searchresults near into in table name

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format this as a subquery :

```
hive -e "use eapi;INSERT into searchresults 'ANZHAUS_GES','Null', q.count from (select count(*) as count from adpubsdmdata WHERE ANZHAUS_GES>=0 && ANZHAUS_GES<=0)q;"
```